# How can I call the web services in cellForRowAtIndexPath method using iOS sdks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to call the web service using **`UITableView`** `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If when i scroll the `tableview` it will calling multiple time, how can i avoid this multiple time web service call.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        WCLTableViewCell *cell = (WCLTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        ImageRecord *imgRecord = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?id=%@&uid=%@",retriveProduct,imgRecord.pid,imgRecord.uid];
                        NSLog(@"url str = %@",urlStr);

                        NSLog(@"service call == %ld", (long)indexPath.row);


                        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
                        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
                        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
                        {
                                NSDictionary *returnJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

                                    NSURL *aUrlValue = [NSURL URLWithString:[returnJSON objectForKey:@"productImage"]];

                                    NSData *imgDataValues=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aUrlValue];
                                    UIImage *img = [self generatePhotoThumbnail:[UIImage imageWithData:imgDataValues]];
                                    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[img CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[img imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                                    if (error)
                                    {
                                        localImagePath = @"";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        localImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",assetURL];    
                                        cell.productImage.image = imgRecord.thumbImage;
                                    }

                                    }];
    }

     return cell;
    }
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You should create a fake cell to show it on tableview, then use async to call service to get data. when it done, reload this cell. Don't call service in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` is call multiple times to create cell based on your `numberOfRow..` so u shouldnt do any request in this method, but implement it in `scrollViewDidScroll` or load it before u show the cell

Comment: @CongTran: So how can i call async to get data in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Could you tell my how can i achieve this.

Comment: @iSara I just wonder why you don't use `SDWebImage` lib to show this image with url, they will do everything for you. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @CongTran: I need to use only apple framework and library. could you tell me how can i call the web service

Comment: I see. So you can avoid to call service multiple time by cache your images you downloaded on your app. md5 your image url and set it as an name of your image you downloaded. Every time you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you search folder you saved on your app first (md5 your url you want to search and search whole folder). If you found this image already downloaded -> show it, else call service and cache then show it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the web service call to run just once you can add it to dispatch once block.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

WCLTableViewCell *cell = (WCLTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

ImageRecord *imgRecord = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?id=%@&uid=%@",retriveProduct,imgRecord.pid,imgRecord.uid];
    NSLog(@"url str = %@",urlStr);

    NSLog(@"service call == %ld", (long)indexPath.row);


    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSDictionary *returnJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

         NSURL *aUrlValue = [NSURL URLWithString:[returnJSON objectForKey:@"productImage"]];

         NSData *imgDataValues=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aUrlValue];
         UIImage *img = [self generatePhotoThumbnail:[UIImage imageWithData:imgDataValues]];
         [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[img CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[img imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
             if (error)
             {
                 localImagePath = @"";
             }
             else
             {

                 localImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",assetURL];

                 cell.productImage.image = imgRecord.thumbImage;

                 }

             }];
         }
    });

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called more than once. Generally speaking, we only set the property of `cell` in this method. You can create an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` which saves something you need request. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,you use the `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to set the `cell`.